# Couchbase Java SDK N1QL UPDATE issue

Tags: java, couchbase, sql++

I'm experimenting with Java and Couchbase 6.0 Community edition using  Java 2.7 SDK.

I'm trying to execute a simple update query from my java application the Couchbase Java 2.7 SDK:

```
String query ="UPDATE admin SET FIELDNAME='TEST'"
N1qlParams params = N1qlParams.build().adhoc(false);
N1qlQuery nquery = N1qlQuery.simple(query, params);
N1qlQueryResult nqr= this.rbucket.query(nquery);
```

And I am getting the following exception (the most meaningful part):

```
com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseException: N1qlQuery Error - {"msg":"syntax error - at UPDATE","code":3000}
```

The actual exception starts like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseException: Error while preparing plan
```

Of course - this query works fine through the Couchbase web UI and I can update without problem.

**Just for info: I tried escaping the single quotes, even tried setting the column to be equal to itself - same error.**

Select queries are executed in a similar manner without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"admin' is not a good name for a bucket, as it is usually related to some reserved keywords, if you still want to use this name, you have to use backticks around it:

```
update `admin` set FIELDNAME = 'TEST'
```

It also might ask you to create a primary index if you don't have one yet.

Comment: Hi, I tried allso  with backticks, that way and it still does not work. I tried also with other bucket - named differently - still not working through the Java SDK.

Comment: try "update `admin` set FIELDNAME = 'TEST'  RETURNING meta().id" , and please post the errors of your other tests

Comment: If you can use spring, I would highly recommend this tutorial https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-spring-boot-spring-data/

Comment: It turned out I somehow got some invisible special character in ... lol All works now..